# What is the cheapest payment processing system for Magento?

Tags: magento, payment-processing

What is the cheapest payment processing system for Magento?
Better if is is the easiest to implement as well

Answer (score 1):

There is not any one answer to this question. The  cost will depend on your transaction mix, as some are free to setup and per year but are expensive per transaction (e.g. PayPal or Google Checkout). Others have an  upfront fee but are cheaper for large volumes of transactions. Some charge a flat fee per transaction, others a percentage.

So, get some comparative costs, assess your likely transaction volume and order values, and work out the most likely. Most major payment gateways have Magento modules already written these days.

Answer (score 0):

Did anyone use Merchant services? http://merchantservices.com/ - they include authorize.net gateway -- is that enough to use Merchant services with Magento. I believe that Merchant services also include a merchant account.

What is the costing for authorize.net? Do they also provide a merchant account?

Paypal WebSite Payments pro? is it a good one ......